# Pyspark - how to handle '^M' character in source file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am reading data from the source file and the source file contains this character: ^M. Because of this, spark is going to a new line, which I do not want. How can I handle this?

Sample data :

```
I | 00683041  |000000000807698|OKC 9800            _____^M                               |0001-01-01|N|1D11|XMS530|2004-03-17|0001-01-01|     |02|00|00|09    |N|0001-01-01|N|0001-01-01|0001-01-01|9998
```

I am using below API to read the code:

```
DF2 = spark.read.option("sep", '|').format("csv").load("file.txt")

 682907 I | 00682907  |000000000807564|OKC 6800            _____^M 
                              |0001-01-01|N|1D11|XMS544|2004-03-10|0001-01-01|     |02|00|00|09    |N|        0001-01-01|N|0001-01-01|0001-01-01|9998
```

Comment: can you add in your source code when you read in the file ?

Comment: Which version of spark are you using?